# How to make an adjustment layer to affect only one layer or one group of layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

In Photoshop I am trying to apply a hue/saturation to just one or a group of layers instead of the entire lot of layers using the "Create new fill or adjustment Layer" button. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: As the most-used program by UI designers in the world, you'd think Photoshop would have a better UI.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Click the third icon from the left, on the bottom of the Adjustment Layer panel (just to the left of the eyeball) to clip the adjustment layer to the one below:

[image: Clip icon]
"Clip" means it will affect only the layer immediately below.

You can also do this by hovering the mouse on the line between the two layers, hold down Alt or Option, and when you see the cursor change to a double circle with a tiny, left-pointing arrow, click.

[image: Clipping cursor]

To have an adjustment layer affect only the layers in a group, put the adjustment layer at the top of the group and change the group's blend mode to "Normal" (as the default is "Pass Through").

Comment: @Sam -- Make sure your adjustment layer is the top layer in a group, select the group (the folder icon), change the Blend Mode to "Normal"

Comment: I think this answer is out of date on Ps v20.